# Draft.JS: the proper way to detect content change

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

There is [onChange](https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/docs/api-reference-editor.html#onchange) event, but it fires also when carret moves or navigation (arrows etc) button being pushed.

I want to detect if **content** was changed. Basically i need to detect this only once when the very first change occur. The dumb way "compare content" may work here, but this is an anti-pattern because this task is too resources-expensive.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since Draft uses an immutable data structure, it doesn't have to be that resource heavy – comparing references should be enough:

```
onChange(newEditorState) {
  const currentContent = this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent()
  const newContent = newEditorState.getCurrentContent()

  if (currentContent !== newContent) {
    // Content has changed
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably not. Immutable.js based data should be compared using Immutable.is(). https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/is

Comment: That's not necessary here, and definitely not recommended. Since you get a **new** `contentState` every time it changes, the cheapest way to know if has changed, is to see if the reference has changed.

Comment: But if you want to check if, for example, the content has changed since it was loaded from the server...

Comment: Yes, then you'd have to use `is()`, but that's not what was asked for here.

Comment: Sure, but it's nice to provide guidance to people who just read the title :-)

Comment: This doesn't work if you only want to detect changes to actual content state (blocks/entities) and not selection.

Comment: This doesn't detect some style changes done by toolbar